# Missing disk space in server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, diskspace

I have a problem guys! I'm setting up a new server, installing MySQL and importing some databases from an old server. But now the server is full! And I don't know where to start to search.

When I did `du -sh` I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tH5g.png

When I did `df -h` I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeWdk.png

So, It appears that I have 80GBb+ missing, and I'll be glad if someone can help me to find that space.

**Details:**

> ```
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5
> LTS Release:    12.04
> Codename:       precise
> ```

Comment: One way this can happen is deleting files which some process has open.  The file info is removed from the directory so you can no longer see the file, but the file is NOT deleted as long as some process still has the file open.  So, for example maybe you deleted the huge log file of some service, but didn't restart the services.  If you can't find it any other way, a reboot will take care of this.

Comment: The first image doesn't show everything so it's a bit useless...

Comment: @JohnHascall Thanks, im applying a reboot! What command should i use for the first image to be usefull? Ill post updates as soon the server has rebooted

Comment: You just can't see the bottom of the image.  Also, in general this site would prefer you paste in text or upload an image rather than linking to an external image that might disappear.

Comment: If you are setting up a new server, why did you choose an OS which is nearly four years old?

Answer (score 0):

Try `lsof -nP | grep -i deleted`
It should show you opened but deleted files